# MySql Group by but still show all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, window-functions

I have the following database

| ID | imagename | testresult | sampleref | uploadedat | orderid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | filename1.png | NULL | ABC123 | 2021-08-19 12:00 | 1002 |
| 2 | filename2.png | NULL | ABC123 | 2021-08-19 13:00 | 1001 |
| 3 | filename3.png | NULL | ABC123 | 2021-08-19 14:00 | 1002 |
| 4 | filename4.png | NULL | ABC123 | 2021-08-19 15:00 | 1001 |

And i am using the SQL query

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM results 
WHERE imagename IS NOT NULL 
  AND testresult IS NULL 
  AND sampleref LIKE 'LAT%' 
ORDER BY testresult IS NULL DESC, uploadedat 
LIMIT 25
```

However I want to group by (but not aggregate group by) the `orderid`, so that the result would be displayed as

| ID | imagename | testresult | sampleref | uploadedat | orderid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | filename1.png | NULL | ABC123 | 2021-08-19 12:00 | 1002 |
| 3 | filename3.png | NULL | ABC123 | 2021-08-19 14:00 | 1002 |
| 2 | filename2.png | NULL | ABC123 | 2021-08-19 13:00 | 1001 |
| 4 | filename4.png | NULL | ABC123 | 2021-08-19 15:00 | 1001 |

Here we are initially sorted by `uploadedat` but then showing the rest of the results with matching `orderid` essentially grouping them together but still showing each row.

I can't use `ORDER BY orderid, uploadedat` as this would put rows 2 & 4 above 1 & 3

What is the solution to this? is it using 2 select statements, the first selecting * with a group by on orderid and orderby uploadedat and then the 2nd with no grouping where orderid = $Row['orderid']? or is there a way to do a JOIN or double Select in a single statement for this?

Thanks?

Comment: Would it help to do `ORDER BY orderid DESC, uploadedat ASC` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sort first by the min `uploadedat` for each `orderid`.

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can use `MIN()` window function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM results
WHERE imagename IS NOT NULL 
  AND testresult IS NULL 
ORDER BY MIN(uploadedat) OVER (PARTITION BY orderid),
         uploadedat
```

For previous versions use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT r1.* 
FROM results r1
WHERE r1.imagename IS NOT NULL 
  AND r1.testresult IS NULL 
ORDER BY (SELECT MIN(r2.uploadedat) FROM results r2 WHERE r2.orderid = r1.orderid),
         r1.uploadedat
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b49fd7a5faf67b864bb9874c79b28065).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ORDER BY orderid desc,uploadedat asc
```

tested in mysql 8.0

```
with cte as
(
select 1002 as id ,'2021-08-19 12:00' as upd
union all
select 1002 as id ,'2021-08-19 14:00' as upd
union all
select 1001 as id ,'2021-08-19 13:00' as upd
union all
select 1001 as id ,'2021-08-19 15:00' as upd
) select * from cte order by id desc,upd asc
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eefd4b80af92802fe28f9de9d3297b05)